# Shared pointer only initialising via std::shared_ptr. The std::make_shared constructor is not working

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, sdl, smart-pointers

I am making a basic game using SDL2 and C++. I have been slowly changing my bad use of raw pointers to safer smart pointers.

The `_window` variable is a private class member:

```
private:
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> _window;
```

**The following code works:**

```
_window = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Game",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
));
```

**The following code does not work:**

```
_window = std::make_shared<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Game",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
));
```

The following error is thrown:

```
C:\...\include\type_traits(984): error C2027: use of undefined type 'SDL_Window'
```

This is very confusing, because `type_traits` is part of the standard library. I am therefore not sure where the source of the error is, but it is not viable to include my entire project here.

What could be causing such an error to be thrown, simply by changing `std::shared_ptr` to `std::make_shared`?

Comment: Both won't work as you have to provide custom deleter.

Comment: Is there a particular way I should do this?

Comment: @Ashley: "*This is very confusing, because type_traits is part of the standard library.*" Just because the site of the error is within the standard library *does not* mean that it is the *source* of that error. Just like if you pass a function a NULL pointer, the NULL pointer access will happen in that function even though it's your code that did the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make_shared` is for creating a new object, not for assuming ownership of an existing one.
The function constructs the object itself, so it needs the class definition.

("Make shared" doesn't mean "make this pointer shared", but "make an object that can be shared". It's the "make" of "make me a pizza", not of "make me a rockstar" - that is, creation, not transformation.)

You can't use `make_shared` here since the only way to create a `SDL_Window` is through `SDL_CreateWindow`.
(And there would be no point since the window already exists.)

You also need to pass a custom deletion function to the constructor, since SDL requires a specific function to destroy the window:

```
_window = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow("Game", ...), SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

Comment: Thanks very much everyone for the answers so far. This is all quite clear now. Also cheers for including that syntax and the additional information about passing the deconstructor.

Comment: That puts a whole new spin on "make me a pizza".

Answer (score 7):

First to address your question: `make_shared` only helps in the case where the resource is acquired with `new` which in this case it's not. You have to make use of the normal `shared_pointer` constructor with the resource returned by `SDL_CreateWindow`. However this isn't the full story, you also have to pass in a deleter that knows how to call `SDL_DestroyWindow` to release the resource.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_shared<T>` is intended to actually *construct* an object of type `T`. `SDL_Window` is an incomplete type which cannot be constructed outside of SDL itself. Objects of that type can only be constructed via SDL calls like `SDL_CreateWindow`.

You should only use `make_shared` when you are constructing the object inside `make_shared` itself. And you're not. So just use the `shared_ptr<T>` directly.